# How to propagate RTCPeerConnection changes to a React component with Mobx state management library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, webrtc, mobx

I'm currently in a project that uses React-native for mobile, React on the web and MobX to create an app that utilises WebRTC to enable users to communicate through video chat.

The problem I'm facing with is that React render is not being triggered by changes on the RTCPeerConnection, like iceConnectionState, signalingState and remote stream changes.

It seems like MobX is not working the way how its described, when using "native entity" like RTCPeerConnection. Even though we intended to track the properties in a MobX way to be kept updated with the property changes.

RoomStore:

```
import { observable } from 'mobx';
import { RTCPeerConnection, RTCMediaStream } from 'react-native-webrtc';

class RoomStore {
    @observable userMediaStream: RTCMediaStream;    
    @observable peerConnection: RTCPeerConnection;
}

export default RoomStore;
```

Component render method:

```
render() {
    const { roomStore } = this.props;
    const peerConnection = roomStore.peerConnection;
    const iceConnectionState = peerConnection.iceConnectionState;

    if (peerConnection.getRemoteStreams().length > 0 && iceConnectionState === 'completed') {
        // display remote stream
    } else {
        // display connecting state
    }
}
```

I was able to come up with a workaround, which is listening on oniceconnectionstate, onsignalingstate, onaddstream and store the existing peerconnection state values, streams separately on the store itself, but it's redundant and isn't clean to duplicate an already existing state just to make the library work. Also as I work myself through the project this creates extra non-desired complexity in the most sensitive part of the application.

My question is that is it possible to just keep a single RTCPeerConnection observable and write clean less error prone code with MobX?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MobX cannot automatically track host environment objects which actually aren't JavaScript objects at all and don't have to play by the rules.

Doing `@observable` before an RTCPeerConnection cannot actually make it observable in a meaningful way.

The only way to add observability here would be to have a separate observable property and listen to the RTCPeerConnection's events:

```
connection.onicecandidate = () => { /* update observable proprety here */ }
connection.oniceconnectionstatechange = () => { /* update observable proprety here */ }
connection.onsignalingstatechange =  { /* update observable proprety here */ }
```

Comment: Thanks for answering Benjamin. This is what I currently do and would like to avoid.

Imagine a render method where you reference some store properties just to receive an update for another object in the store that you actually working with.

This seems very fishy to me, although this is what I might have to go with.

Comment: @dropout as someone who is in the mobx team and also works with webrtc for a living - I don't see how we can make this work. This is because RTCPeerConnection is a DOM host object and not an actual JavaScript object. I would contain the relationship between the RTCPeerConnection and MobX in one place (in the model layer) and then expose MobX (or plain JS) objects anyway. Even without mobx I'd recommend wrapping RTCPeerConnection since you have to deal with two APIs anyway (the promises one and the callback one) or use a library which MobX will work with gladly.

Comment: The libraries we are using react-native-webrtc and webrtc-adapter are having unified promise based APIs and would like to ditch our existing wrapper :) We prefer not to depend on third party libraries too much because we are concerned if library providerscan catch up in time with the ever changing webrtc specification/implementation. We have an app in production for 2 years now. It might be worthwhile to add a limitations section to mobx that some use cases are limited because of the design of the library. Thanks anyhow I'll accept your answer in a few days if no better answer will come.